# Why UrlGenerator generate path without host and scheme in Silex?

Tags: symfony, silex

I try to generate url with UrlGenerator in Silex but it seems that UrlGenerator generates only content of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` without `http://localhost` . So instead of `http://localhost/silex/rest-blog/web/blog/posts` I have `/silex/rest-blog/web/blog/posts`. Do you have any idea why?

My code:

```
$app['url_generator']->generate('blog.posts.index');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To generate an absolute URL you have to do that :

```
$app['url_generator']->generate('blog.posts.index', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

Comment: The third parameter is `$referenceType` of type `int` and should be one of the constants defined in `UrlGeneratorInterface`, not a hardcoded value (in your case even of the wrong type `bool`).

Comment: @RoyalKnight true, they changed that, I updated my answer. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by @raphaël-malié is not working for me (Silex 1.3)

Digging through the [UrlGenerator](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.html) documentation, I've come with the following solution:

```
$url = $app["url_generator"]->generate("blog.posts.index", array(), $app["url_generator"]::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```